# How to get React-Dates DayPicker single DateController to work with custom input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

How can I get the airbnb datepicker with custom input to open and close the calendar?

This is the custom date input https://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/daypickersingledatecontroller--with-custom-input

I want this to work like this example: https://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/sdp-input-props--default

The calendar should open and close for the custom input like it does with the built-in one

Answer (score 0):

You can use DayPickerRangeController for this. It only returns the calender and you can show it when user click on you custom input field or some other thing.

check this example
https://gist.github.com/osifo/984cd60dce5d6abb49b6923ffa580638

doc:
DayPickerRangeController: https://github.com/react-dates/react-dates?tab=readme-ov-file#daypickerrangecontroller